# Is there a way to pass a regex capture to a block in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, block

I have a hash with a `regex` for the key and a `block` for the value. Something like the following:

```
{ 'test (.+?)' => { puts $1 } }
```

Not *exactly* like that, obviously, since the block is being stored as a Proc, but that's the idea.

I then have a regex match later on that looks a lot like this

```
hash.each do |pattern, action|
    if /#{pattern}/i.match(string)
        action.call
    end
end
```

The idea was to store the block away in the hash to make it a bit easier for me to expand upon in the future, but now the `regex` capture doesn't get passed to the block. Is there a way to do this cleanly that would support any number of captures I put in the `regex` (as in, some `regex` patterns may have 1 capture, others may have 3)?

Comment: This doesn't address your question, but why store the pattern as a string instead of a regex?

Comment: No real reason. I'm using a method to store the hash so it's easier to read (`on(pattern, &block) hash[pattern] = block` is basically the method I'm using), and it seemed easier to write `on 'test (.+?)' do puts $1 end`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you pass the match data into your procs?

```
hash.each do |pattern, action|
  if pattern.match(string)
    action.call($~)
  end
end
```

Your hash would become:

```
{ /test (.+?)/i => lambda { |matchdata| puts matchdata[1] } }
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to use `matchdata[1]` instead of `first`, but that works great.

Comment: Oh right, I should have tested that first.  I've changed my answer for future's sake.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Hash.find` which walks the hash elements, passing them into a block, one at a time. The one that returns `true` wins:

Something like this:

```
hash = {/foo/ => lambda { 'foo' }, /bar/ => lambda { 'bar' } }
str = 'foo'
puts hash.find{ |n,v| str =~ n }.to_a.last.call
```

Obviously I'm using `lambda` but it's close enough. And, if there was no match you need to handle nil values. For the example I chained `to_a.last.call` but in real life you'd want to react to a nil otherwise Ruby will get mad.

If you are searching through a lot of patterns, or processing a lot of text, your search will be slowed down by having to recompile the regex each time. I'd recommend storing the keys as regex objects to avoid that.